# Remove fields / colums with zero "0" values in shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, fields-attributes, delete

I'm working on different project each day. At the end I would like to delete the fields that have zero "0" values in. The fields with the zero's will differ from project to project. So the model should look thru each field and if the field has zero's it must delete the field. In the attached image example I would like to delete DOL_J1 and GYPSUM_1. Because of the amount of project I would like to build a model to automate this.

Will this be possible with ModelBuilder or do I need to use Python? I'm not that familiar with Python and would prefer ModelBuilder.

I have an ArcMap license

[image]

Comment: Do you want to delete a field if all the values are = 0? Or if at least one value =0?

Comment: If all the values are = 0. (I did not show the whole table. The DOL_j1 field have some values lower down)

Comment: I don't know how easy this is to do in ModelBuilder, but it sure isn't very hard in Python. Pseudocode: 1 List fields. 2 Search cursor for all fields, store the field names for those who only contains 0. 3 Delete said fields. 4 Save output. It is possible that you can have some help from [ET Geowizards](ian-ko.com) too.

Comment: Getting this to work in Model Builder would probably be pretty tricky--might want to investigate [Summary Stats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple approach that uses `numpy` and will handle fields with null values (if you don't want to, then change `null_value` to any other number):

```py
import arcpy

fc = "<my fc>"
# Get all numeric fields that aren't required.
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.Describe(fc).fields
            if f.type.upper() in ['DOUBLE', 'INTEGER', 'SINGLE', 'SMALLINTEGER']
            and not f.required]

# Convert to numpy array, casting nulls to 0.
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(fc, fields, null_value=0)

# Find all fields whose sum are 0.
delete = [field for field in fields if not arr[field].sum()]
print("Deleting '{}'".format(", ".join(delete)))
arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, delete)
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything on your script? I only changed the fc = "c:\Temp\dbfile.dbf". I get the same error: Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'

Comment: @ThinusEnslin, you'll need 10.1 SP1+ to access the data access module (`da`).

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.0 SP5

Answer (score 1):

Model builder does not have the functionality you seek, you will need to do this using python.

Below is the code that will do this, obviously you need to edit `myTable` and the parameter `"SmallInteger"` to suit your needs

```py
import arcpy
import array
myTable = r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\tblTest"

# Get list of fields
fieldList = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(myTable,"","SmallInteger")]
print "Fields to check: " + str(fieldList)

# Create an array
initializer = [0 for x in range(0,len(fieldList),1)]
total = array.array("f",initializer)
print "total array initialized to: " + str(total)

# Sum the values in the fields and store in array total
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myTable,fieldList) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for i in range(0,len(fieldList) -1,1):
            total[i] = total[i] + row[i]
print "total array after summing: " + str(total)

# Delete fields if sum is zero
for i in range(0,len(fieldList),1):
    if total[i] == 0:
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(myTable,fieldList[i])
        print "Deleted: " + fieldList[i]
```

With those two variables set you can simply drop this code into the python command line window and execute it that way. This code assumes that all rows in your fields have a value, so NULL values will probably blow this code up.

Comment: I wonder, would a sort  and checking if first and last values = 0 be faster than a cursor?

Comment: Possibly, something to try I guess? I have found stepping through a cursor once is often a fast approach.

Comment: @recurvata summing will usually be faster than sorting, even more so as the list gets larger. Compare `python -m timeit -s "import random;r=[random.random() for i in range(10000)]" "sum(r)"` with `r.sort()` or `sorted(r)`.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I edit the myTable and SmallInteger, but I get an error message: Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'

Comment: What version of Arcgis are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.0 SP5

Comment: OK that is the source of the problem. the `da` module never existed in that version of ArcMap. You need to study the help file and look at how that version of `arcpy` uses SearchCursors, it will require a minor change in the code.