# Calculate all 'Null' integer fields to '0'?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, null

Is there an easy way to calculate all `Null` integer fields to `0` in a GDB?

Selecting `Null` values and field calculating each column to `0` is not a viable option as I need to do this for a few hundred columns across multiple layers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this for many fields with some Python. This is a stand alone example, but it'd be easy to write this into a script/Python toolbox. Or you could embed this into another loop and do this on a list of feature classes/tables.
Keep in mind this approach will make the changes to *all* short/long integer fields:

```py
import arcpy

features = 'SomeGDB.gdb/SomeFeatureClass'
fields = arcpy.ListFields(features)
fnames = [x.name for x in fields if x.type in ['Integer','SmallInteger']]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(features, fnames) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        updated = False # keep track if we actually update something
        for v in range(len(fnames)):
            if row[v] is None:
                row[v] = 0
                updated = True
        # only update the row if we changed something
        if updated: rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1138, in ListFields
    return gp.listFields(dataset, wild_card, field_type)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 346, in listFields
    self._gp.ListFields(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: <unprintable IOError object>

Comment: @Ryan Sounds like it couldn't open that dataset for some reason. It may be open in an instance of arcmap somewhere, etc.

Comment: I'll try to test it with another dataset tonight and see if this works. I'm not fluent in python and this is my first time using Python toolbox. The only thing I should have to change in your povided script is point to my gdb/feature class right? Thanks!

Comment: instead of maintaining `updated` just use a list comprehension and compare that. `newRow = [0 if v is None else v for v in row]` and then `if newRow == row`. The fastest would likely be similar to [my answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/201488/19311). Instead of deleting fields, you are casting None to 0 when converting to `numpy`.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, at a minimum. Also check to be sure you have it spelled correctly. Ideally, a Python Toolbox would have parameters so that you could specify it as an input, but there's nothing wrong with starting off simple as  you learn. Also, if you are using a Python toolbox, be sure to refresh it or restart ArcGIS after you make changes.

Comment: @Paul You certainly could, although you'd also be storing an entire copy of the row. Either way it's negligible, so I'm not sure one would be better than the other, although I tend to go towards more readability. And I did think of going the NumPy route, it would certainly be less code, but again the difference would be small in this case and you could end up using much more memory since you have to load the all values into memory at the same time. You still end up reading every single row, and then updating every single row, even if it's within the API instead of explicitly in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Select all Null values from the field (FIELD IS NULL) -> Right click the field -> Field Calculate -> Field = 0

Comment: I know this is one way but it is slow and I want to avoid it. I need to do this for a few hundred fields on multiple layers.

Comment: @Ryan please update your question with this very relevant information.  Tell us what you've tried and why that doesn't work for you.